Infinity Minus Infinity When Computing Electric Potential Difference
I am working on a problem involving a polarized cylinder with its axis aligned along the $z$-axis. The cylinder has a height $L$, radius
$R$ and a constant, uniform polarization
$P$ that is parallel to the $z$-axis and oriented in the positive $z$-direction. No free charges are mentioned, so I assume the only charges present are the bound surface charges at the top and bottom surfaces, with surface charge densities +$P$ and −$P$, respectively.
Given this setup, I am tasked with calculating the electric potential at a point on the $z$-axis located a height
$h$ above the top surface of the cylinder. While the problem is straightforward if one integrates the potential due to infinitesimal bound charge
$dq$ on each surface, I wanted to calculate the electric field at the same point (valid for a point at any height from the top lid !!and in the axis!!) in order to calculate the potential through the potential difference - assuming potential is zero at infinity -.
However, when summing the contributions of the electric fields from the two surfaces and computing the potential difference via integration, I encounter an
$\infty -\infty$ problem. I end up with the indefinite integral $\sqrt{(h+L)^2+R^2}-\sqrt{h^2+R^2}$.
where one of the integral limits is infinity ($h$ is my variable here although you could call it $z$ too). Can I assume these terms cancel out in infinity? I thought of doing some more manipulation, as in $t=z+L$ or something, but I am not really sure about how to approach the infinity here. Any help is appreciated and if more information about the problem is needed I'll gladly provide it.

I just thought of getting a (h+L)^2 factor out of both square roots and then I'd be left with (h+L)(sqrt(1+R^2/(h+L)^2)-sqrt((h^2+R^2)/(h+L)^2. This also bugs me quite a bit, as for it to be zero then as h approaches infinity then h^2/(h^2+2hL+L^2) would have to be 1

So I figured out that the terms multiplied by (h+L) do go to zero, however h+L goes to infinity, so should I try and apply L'Hopital or something? I just can't continue with this anymore, it's pure suffering

Actually, we need to see which integral you are considering.

The result of that infinite limit should be $L$ instead of 0. The way to show this is to use the definition of an improper integral:
$$
\int^\infty_a f(x) dx = \lim_{b\to\infty}\int^b_a f(x) dx.
$$
Your result then becomes
$$
\sqrt{(h+L)^2+R^2}-\sqrt{h^2+R^2}\Big|^\infty_a = \lim_{b\to\infty}\sqrt{(h+L)^2+R^2}-\sqrt{h^2+R^2}\Big|^b_a,
$$
with upper limit $
\lim_{b\to\infty}\sqrt{(b+L)^2+R^2}-\sqrt{b^2+R^2}$.
We can treat $b\gg L,R$ in this limit, so expanding $(b+L)^2$ we get
\begin{align*}
\lim_{b\to\infty}\sqrt{b^2+2bL+L^2+R^2}-\sqrt{b^2+R^2}&\approx\lim_{b\to\infty}\sqrt{b^2+2bL}-\sqrt{b^2}\\
&=\lim_{b\to\infty}b\sqrt{1+\frac{2L}{b}}-b\\
&\approx\lim_{b\to\infty}b\left(1+\frac{L}{b}\right)-b = L,
\end{align*}
using the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ at the end.

It is analytically nicer to treat this via this alternative method: $$\begin{align}\tag1 &\lim_{b\to\infty}\sqrt{(b+L)^2+R^2}-\sqrt{b^2+R^2}\\tag2=&\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{[(b+L)^2+R^2]-[b^2+R^2]}{\sqrt{(b+L)^2+R^2}+\sqrt{b^2+R^2}}\\tag3=&\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{2bL+L^2}{b[\sqrt{1+[R/(b+L)]^2}+\sqrt{1+(R/b)^2}]+L\sqrt{1+[R/(b+L)]^2}}\end  {align}$$ and then the numerator and denominator can be easily divided by $2b$, and then it is safe and obvious that the limit is $L$
